# Android - Use of navigation with activities and fragments - Binary XML file Error

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-architecture-components

I have an application composed of one activity and several fragments, as recommanded by Google.

```
- MainActivity
  - LobbyFragment
  - GameFragment
  - ...
```

I also wanted to use the navigation map
[image: navigation map]

I put a menu in the Activity to have everywhere, and then I would like to switch the content of the page.

To do this as shown in the [fragment tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create), i made the `activitymain.xml` to later switch the content of the `FragmentContainerView` between fragments.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.application.AppBarOverlay">
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.my.application.LobbyFragment" /> <!--Here is failure-->

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But, at this point, when I compile, I have :
`Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.application/com.my.application.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView`

And where to put the Activity in the navigation map ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation link](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create) you referenced uses the traditional fragment transaction by directly accessing `supportFragmentManager`; but it turns out from your post that you use [Navigation Architecture components](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) instead.

In navigation components, you are not supposed to use a particular fragment class in the `android:name` property, instead the `navController` takes care of that using `NavHostFragment`

To, fix this, please replace

```
android:name="com.my.application.LobbyFragment"
```

With

```
android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
```

Also, you need to reference the name of the navGraph in that with `app:navGraph` attribute; assuming it's named as `nav_graph`:

```
app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It seemed to worked even with the good android:name only. What does `app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"` do ?

Comment: If i understand well, this specific navigation graph is used for this specific FragmentContainerView. So there is no use to place the activity in it ?

Comment: @Foxhunt That is right, it's not referenced from the activity unless you need to programmatically modify some fragments in the graph; and that occurs in odd and advanced cases.

Comment: In your app, you could have another `FragmentContainerView` that references another `navGraph`, so a particular  `FragmentContainerView` is tied to a single `navGraph`