# Android - Activity and Fragment initialization

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, layout-inflater

I have an application composed of one activity and several fragments, as recommanded by Google. Other details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69761201/android-use-of-navigation-with-activities-and-fragments-binary-xml-file-erro). I would like to keep a menu still and to switch my fragments in the container in the center.

### activity_main.xml

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:someProperties="propertiesValues">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:someProperties="propertiesValues" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_map"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:someProperties="propertiesValues" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: activity_main.xml]

### MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        println("Activity creation")
        val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        println("Activity creation part 2")
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)

        User.initSharedPref(this)
    }
```

### Fragment

```
private lateinit var mylist: MutableList<String>>
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    println("Fragment creation")

    mylist = User.loadScenarioList()
}
```

### User

```
object User
{
  private lateinit var sharedPref : SharedPreferences

  fun initSharedPref(context: Context){
    sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("JeuDePisteKtPreferenceFileKey",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
  }

  fun loadList(): MutableList<String>> {
      val json = sharedPref.getString(KEY_LIST, "") ?: ""
      if (json == "") return mutableListOf()
      return Json.decodeFromString(json)
  }

}
```

### Problem encountered

When i start the activity, it initialize a variable `sharedPref`  as shown in code.

But when in fragment onCreate i use this variable (`mylist = User.loadScenarioList()`), the binding line in activity fail with `Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView` as shown in logcat below

### Logcat & error

Here is the full logcat, we can see the the second sout is missing, but with no error thrown at this point.

[image: logcat]

Comment: There is never a crash without an error message. Check to make sure Logcat is working correctly and not filtering you logs. The question you linked is irrelevant for an Activity. This is the right place to inflate the view in an Activity, and your code looks fine.

Comment: Care to elaborate the `menu` here is ActionBar menu or those `fab` button?

Comment: The crash actually happen later because a Lateinit property i initialise at the end of my Activity.OnCreate() is used in my Fragment.OnCreate(). For debug i also added print, wich is not reach, but without error. i added it above with the logcat

Comment: I spoted the problem more precisly, changed the question with it. The real error is sort of mixed with the fragment error, but i did a breakpoint just before the line `ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)`, and then evaluate it, and it return `Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here came from the order of creation call

We can see it in the corrected code logcat
[image: logcat]

The activity onCreate is called first, but the first inflate call the fragment OnCreate, before resuming the activity OnCreate.

So every variable used in the fragment onCreate should be initialized before inflate call